# How to return reference or copy

Tags: c++, reference

I have the following code:

```
EdgeSet Graph::GetNodeOutcomingEdges(long long NodeId) {
    //NodeEdgeMap is an unordereded_map
    NodeEdgeMap::iterator it = NodeOutcomingEdges.find(NodeId);
    if (it != NodeOutcomingEdges.end()) {
        return *(*(it)).second;
    }
    return EdgeSet();
}
```

and then..

```
EdgeSet& OutcomingEdges = RoadGraph.GetNodeOutcomingEdges(Expandee.GetId());
```

Because the value does not have to be in the map, I have to somehow account for it, under ideal circumstances, return an empty (new) EdgeSet. I could throw and exception, but is it necessary? This compiles fine under VS (probably already accounts for RVO), but not so with g++.

Comment: Why not publish an iterator?

Comment: VC++ has a long-standing bug that allows non-const references to be bound to temporaries, which is not valid C++

Comment: Which do you want to return? A reference or a copy?

Comment: As soon as g++ threw that error, I knew there was something wrong with the code, I just have no idea how to fix it elegantly.

Comment: Preferably a reference, as the object could be large. But then my question is, how do I return a reference if I have to create an empty one?

Comment: Return a pointer instead?

Comment: EdgeSet& Graph::GetNodeOutcomingEdges(long long NodeId) {
    //NodeEdgeMap is an unordereded_map
    NodeEdgeMap::iterator it = NodeOutcomingEdges.find(NodeId);
    if (it != NodeOutcomingEdges.end()) {
        return *(*(it)).second;
    } static EdgeSet emptySet;
    return emptySet;
}

Comment: You could use `boost::optional`

Comment: @oopscene, I initially said that wasn't valid C++, because I missed the `static EdgeSet emptySet;` part. Posting that much code in a comment (without markup) makes it very hard to read, it should be an answer

Comment: The static trick is a neat one, and one that I will surely use in the future some time. It would be great for my case, but I can see a case where a user of your code inserts into that static object and it is no longer empty. Thanks though.

Comment: btw "outcoming" is not a word. Outgoing, or incoming, not outcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a possible way of doing it: within your Graph class, define an empty member variable of type EdgeSet, with some attribute that identifies it as empty, such as an "mEmptyFlag" boolean:

```
class Graph {
   ...
   static EdgeSet mEmptyNode(params defining empty node here);
   ...
}

EdgeSet Graph::GetNodeOutcomingEdges(long long NodeId) {
    //NodeEdgeMap is an unordereded_map
    NodeEdgeMap::iterator it = NodeOutcomingEdges.find(NodeId);
    if (it != NodeOutcomingEdges.end()) {
        return *(*(it)).second;
    }
    return Graph::mEmptyNode;
}

callerFunct {
     EdgeSet& OutcomingEdges = RoadGraph.GetNodeOutcomingEdges(Expandee.GetId());
     if (OutcomingEdges.mEmptyflag==true) {
            deal with empty node here
     } else {
          ....
     }
 }
```

Or even better for encapsulation, hide mEmptyFlag and provide an "IsEmpty()" function for EdgeSet.

Comment: Can the static object be const so that I can be sure no one will call a nonconst method on it? If so, I think this is most elegant solution given.

Comment: static and const would be redundant. Use either, const is fine. As I mentioned at the end, you could make the flag private, and provide an IsEmpty function, too.

Comment: The static object can't be const if you want to return a non-const reference from `GetNodeOutcomingEdges`.

Answer (score 1):

```
EdgeSet& Graph::GetNodeOutcomingEdges(long long NodeId) {
    //NodeEdgeMap is an unordereded_map
    NodeEdgeMap::iterator it = NodeOutcomingEdges.find(NodeId);
    if (it != NodeOutcomingEdges.end()) {
        return *(*(it)).second;
    }
    static EdgeSet emptySet;
    return emptySet;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the caller has no access to the static object created inside the function so it cannot use it to check if it returned an error or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually want to return a reference, to allow the caller to modify the returned object, you could return a pointer to the found object, or a null pointer if it's not found:

```
EdgeSet* Graph::GetNodeOutcomingEdges(long long NodeId) {
    //NodeEdgeMap is an unordereded_map
    NodeEdgeMap::iterator it = NodeOutcomingEdges.find(NodeId);
    if (it != NodeOutcomingEdges.end()) {
        return it->second;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, return a `boost::optional<EdgeSet&>` which can be empty.

But you should not return a reference "just because", you should return a reference if you want the caller to be able to refer to the same object as is stored in the map, and also be able to modify it. Otherwise, returning a copy, or maybe a const-reference, would be better.

Comment: Think I'm gonna do just that. Seems like the best cure, even if it means using a raw pointer. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

```
NodeEdgeMap::iterator Graph::GetNodeOutcomingEdges(long long NodeId) {
    return NodeOutcomingEdges.find(NodeId);
}
```

Comment: This is neither a reference or a copy.

Comment: Yeap, but in this way he can verify in a standard way if the object exists or not in his map. I am not sure if returning a concrete but empty object is completely correct.

Comment: The NodeOutcomingEdges object is not visible from the place I'm calling the method. How do I test for end()?

Comment: NodeEdgeMap::iterator Graph::end() { return NodeOutcomingEdges.end(); }

Comment: Why am I being modded down? I think the solution I am giving here is completely valid.

Comment: Without explanation as to remove-votes, I vote to keep this here

Comment: it's valid, but when you need to add another member function to detect whether the return value can be dereferenced or not, it is not very useful. Returning a pointer to the element has similar properties to an iterator, but can be easily compared to see if it's null.